# "if var and var2 == getSomeValue()" in python - if the first is false, is the second statement evaluated?'

Tags: python, short-circuiting

I have some code like this:

```
if var:
    if var2 == getSomeValue()
```

This could be in a single expression.

```
if var and var2 == getSomeValue():
```

...but `getSomeValue()` can only be called if `var` is True.

So, when calling `if var and var2 == getSomeValue()`, are both evaluated by the interpreter, or the evaluation stops at `var` if `False`? Where I can find this information on python documentation? (I didn't know what to search...:/ )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called short-circuiting, and Python does it, so you're good.

UPDATE: Here's a quick example.

```
>>> def foo():
...     print "Yay!"
... 
>>> if True and foo() is None:
...     print "indeed"
... 
Yay!
indeed
>>> if False and foo() is None:
...     print "nope"
...
```

UPDATE 2: Putting the [relevant PEP (308)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) in my answer so it doesn't get overlooked in the excellent comment from @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS.

Comment: The first answer, and naming the behavior as short-circuiting is exactly what I was looking for. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation Thanks! And here is the PEP about it: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/

Comment: @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS Any time.

Comment: @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS +1 for the link to the PEP.

Answer (score 2):

The second item isn't evaluated - you could verify this with a simple program:

```
def boo():
  print "hi"
  return True

a = False
b = True

if a and b == boo():
  print "hi2"
```

Running it produces no output, so you can see that `boo()` is never called.

Answer (score 2):

If `var` is `False`, evaluation stops.

See the *Short-Circuit Behavior* section in [PEP 308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/).

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation getSomeValue won't be evaluated:

```
var = False
if var and foo():
   print "here"
else:
   print "there"

def foo():
   print "In foo"
   return False
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#index-1003) says that `and` and `or` are short-circuiting, so no, `var2 == getSomeValue()` won't be evaluated if `var` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Re "*I didn't know what to search*"

You don't need to search when there's an index available:

Browse to the [Python home page](http://python.org/). Successively click on

- DOCUMENTATION
- Current Docs
- index (it's in the top right corner)
- A

Scroll down until you see

```
and
    bitwise
    operator
```

You don't want `bitwise`, click on `operator`.

If you are on Windows, you have the manuals on your computer, with a nice-enough GUI interface. Check out the Contents / Index / Search / Favorites panes near the top left corner.